# Camel-JoSQL support for camel 3

Tags: apache-camel

Can't find camel-josql library for camel 3. Is this going to come in future? Any reason why it's not released with camel-3

Latest artifact on camel-josql :
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-josql/2.25.1

Latest artifact on camel-josql-starter :
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-josql-starter/2.25.1

Comment: camel-josql is deprected but camel-josql-starter is not, then why it's not supported in camel 3

Answer (score 0):

camel-josql was flagged as deprecated in Camel 2.x a long time ago. See the component documentation:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.25.1/components/camel-josql/src/main/docs/sql-language.adoc

Hence why it was removed for Camel 3.x. There's some more background here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10973

And in the commit that added the deprecation notice:

https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/62e569632b8ff83c488e97b601c7882fc3ab118c